# Get Specific Data In a Table based on status

Tags: sql, postgresql

So i am having an issue regarding a query to get the latest data based on status

For example. I have a table like these

**Schema (PostgreSQL v12)**

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  id INTEGER,
  user_id INTEGER,
  product VARCHAR(20),
  status VARCHAR(20)
  );
  
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,1,'WALK','ACTIVE');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2,1,'RUN','ACTIVE');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(3,2,'WALK','INACTIVE');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(4,2,'RUN','ACTIVE');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(5,3,'WALK','UPDATING');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(6,3,'RUN','ACTIVE');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(7,4,'WALK','UPDATING');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(8,4,'RUN','INACTIVE');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(9,2,'RUN','UPDATING');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id | user_id | product | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | WALK | ACTIVE |
| 2 | 1 | RUN | ACTIVE |
| 3 | 2 | WALK | INACTIVE |
| 4 | 2 | RUN | ACTIVE |
| 5 | 3 | WALK | UPDATING |
| 6 | 3 | RUN | ACTIVE |
| 7 | 4 | WALK | UPDATING |
| 8 | 4 | RUN | INACTIVE |
| 9 | 2 | RUN | UPDATING |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iwxe23ngagwq9xKWQa1icX/0)

Basically, i need a query to get the latest of user_id status and the status only for active and updating. But, if active and updating is exists, they pick the active one.
So from this table, the result should be

| user_id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ACTIVE |
| 2 | ACTIVE |
| 3 | ACTIVE |
| 4 | UPDATING |

i tried this, but it only return the latest value

```
SELECT distinct on (user_id) user_id, status
FROM test
ORDER BY user_id DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option:

```
SELECT distinct on (user_id) user_id, status
FROM test
where status != 'INACTIVE'
ORDER BY user_id, array_position('{ACTIVE,UPDATING}', status)
```

When you do `distinct on` the `order by` is mandatory for the distinct field(s) (`user_id` in this case), but you *also* need to specify the sort criteria after that to determine which distinct record to show.

In other words, you want to only show one record by user id, but HOW do you determine which one?  That's why you need the second argument in the order by.

Comment: woah, that's new. thanks for your answer ! :)

Answer (score 0):

using distinct on

```
SELECT distinct on (user_id) user_id, status
FROM test where status in ('ACTIVE','UPDATING')
ORDER BY user_id asc,id DESC
```

[demo link in fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iwxe23ngagwq9xKWQa1icX/0)

Answer (score 0):

We can user ROW_NUMBER() in a CTE with ORDER BY id DESC so that number 1 is the latest row.

```
with cte as
(select
 user_id,
 status,
 row_number() over (partition by user_id order by id desc) rn
 from test
 where status in ('ACTIVE','UPDATING')
                  )
 select * from cte   
 where rn = 1
 order by user_id;
```

| user_id | status | rn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ACTIVE | 1 |
| 2 | ACTIVE | 1 |
| 3 | ACTIVE | 1 |
| 4 | UPDATING | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iwxe23ngagwq9xKWQa1icX/0)

Comment: if the data can be updated, can we still use the same method?

Comment: If the primary key is in the CTE we can do `update CTE set ...`  instead of `select ... From CTE`